# How to maximise the use of the GPU without having blocks waiting to be scheduled?

Tags: cuda, gpu

A device query on my Titan-XP shows that I have 30 multiprocessors with a maximum number of 2048 threads per multiprocessor. Is it correct to think that the maximum number of threads that can simultaneously be executed physically on the hardware is 30 * 2048? I.e: will a kernel configuration like the following exploit this?

```
kernel<<<60, 1024>>>(...);
```

I'd really like to physically have the maximum number of blocks executing while avoiding having blocks waiting to be scheduled. Here's the full output of device query:

```
CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "TITAN Xp"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          9.0 / 9.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    6.1
  Total amount of global memory:                 12190 MBytes (12781682688 bytes)
  (30) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:     3840 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1582 MHz (1.58 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             5705 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              384-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 3145728 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(131072), 2D=(131072, 65536), 3D=(16384, 16384, 16384)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(32768), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(32768, 32768), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     No
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 4 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 9.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 9.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = TITAN Xp
Result = PASS
```

Comment: "I'd really like to physically have the maximum number of blocks executing while avoiding having blocks waiting to be scheduled" - probably not. That is, it's unlikely that trying to achieve that will be useful to you. @RobertCrovella's answer points in the right direction though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your conclusion is correct.  The maximum number of threads that can be "in-flight" is 2048 * # of SMs for all GPUs supported by CUDA 9 or CUDA 9.1.  (Fermi GPUs, supported by CUDA 8, are a bit lower at 1536 * # of SMs)

This is an upper bound, and the specifics of your kernel (resource utilization) may mean that fewer than this number can actually be "resident" or "in flight".  This is in the general topic of GPU occupancy.  CUDA includes an occupancy calculator spreadsheet and also a programmatic [occupancy API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__OCCUPANCY.html#group__CUDART__OCCUPANCY) to help determine this, for your specific kernel.

The usual kernel strategy to have a limited number of threads (e.g. 60 * 1024 in your case) handle an arbitrary data set size is to use some form of a construct called a [grid striding loop](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/).